# Mi página no carga al pinchar desde Google Search

Tags: google-search

Básicamente mi problema es que cuando mi página sale en la búsqueda de Google, al pinchar sobre ella se queda pensando y no redirige.

Si entro como incógnito no hay ningún problema, y si pincho sobre abrir en pestaña nueva, también se me abre sin problema.

Estoy utilizando django para el website, que yo sepa no hay nada cacheado, y el término de búsqueda (Esto lo eliminaré si me lo pide un administrador) es transeop.

El problema es que yo soy el desarrollador de la página, y varios clientes me han reportado ese problema. Necesitaría saber que está pasando y si a alguien le ha pasado alguna vez para una solución global.

Answer (score 1):

En el navegador pruebe a abrir las herramientas de desarrollador (DevTools) con la tecla F12 y seleccione la pestaña de Red (Network, en inglés) antes de clicar el enlace de Google.

Pulse el enlace y compruebe qué se queda cargando. Si es el sitio web al que intenta acceder (lo más probable) , pruebe a borrar los datos del sitio:

- En Chrome/Edge en la pestaña "Application" de las DevTools -> Storage -> Clear site data.
- En Firefox, en la barra superior sobre el candado -> Limpiar cookies y datos del sitio

Una vez hecho eso, reinicie el navegador y pruebe a acceder desde Google.

Comment: Sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Gracias.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas ¿puedes facilitar algo más de información en la pregunta? Si no, es imposible saber que otra cosa podría causar el problema.
¿Ocurre solo entrando desde Google? ¿Ocurre desde otros buscadores u otros sitios web por enlace?

Comment: Buenas. No he querido poner pantallazos porque no se como está de permitido dar de publicidad a las páginas en google. Pero el tema es ese, pinchas en este buscador y la página no redirige y se queda pensando. Si entro como incógnito no hay ningún problema, y si pincho sobre abrir en pestaña nueva, también se me abre sin problema.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas Prueba a borrar los datos del sitio en Google, puede que sea cosa de tu perfil del navegador o alguna extensión.

Comment: Ya lo hice y sigue igual. El problema es que yo soy el desarrollador de la página, y varios clientes me han reportado ese problema. Necesitaría saber que está pasando y si a alguien le ha pasado alguna vez para una solución global.